Having trouble accessing the elements of an array, in a structure, in an array
public struct player
        {
            public int[] PlayerHistory;
            public Boolean Absent;

            public player(Boolean b)
            {
                PlayerHistory = new int[20];
                Absent = b;
            }
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            player[] Player = new player[10];
            player[0].Absent = true;
            Player[0].PlayerHistory[0] = -1;
        }


Whenever I run these lines of code, the algorithm works just fine, until it reaches the last line (Player[0].PlayerHistory[0] = -1), where the following error pops up: NullRefferenceException was unhandled. And I have no idea why, or how to access this data. Interestingly, I can modify the boolean data just fine, I'm just having trouble with the array. Any help would be appreciated.
I've tried reading, writing and editing the values in these arrays, and every time the same error just keeps popping up.

"the algorithm works just fine, until it reaches the last line" - That's simply untrue for the code shown.  You have compilation errors which would prevent this code from executing in the first place.

You need to initialize your players before accessing the array.
// Initialize the first player
Player[0] = new player(true);

You can do this really easily in a for-loop for each player if you need.
You created a struct, not a class so they are not automatically initialized.

"so they are not automatically initialized" - This is a bit misleading.  The player instances are indeed initialized.  (Otherwise the previous line of code would fail when setting the Absent property.)  However, that initialization is not making use of the constructor, so the PlayerHistory member on the struct is what doesn't get initialized.  Aside from that, the suggestion here to explicitly call that constructor would produce the desired result.
